# Expect Tcl pattern match failure

Tags: unix, tcl, expect

I am new to Expect  and Tcl. I am writing a code  using expect in Tcl to match a pattern alone(ie without the pattern being a sub string in a given string).Code is given below:

```
 package require Expect
 expect  "^hi$" { send "pattern matched" }; # hi is the pattern to be matched
```

But the code do not detect hi. If the code is modified as below it works when the pattern comes in the first part of the string

```
 package require Expect
 expect  "^hi" { send "pattern matched" }
```

If the code is modified as below, it is not working even though it is expected to match the pattern at the end of the string

```
 package require Expect
 expect  "hi$" { send "pattern matched" }
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Please help

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed a bit mysterious.

`$` is the end of a string anchor and it looks like that the line end is captured before the end of the string. With this in mind you can do it with:

```
expect "Hi\n$" { puts "Wow" }
```

Be aware that `\n` is working on linux but maybe not on other console types!

Comment: You might need to match dos-style line endings: `expect -re "hi\r?\n"`

Comment: @Kiaus Its working with your suggession, but for all the above codes ie using ^ and \n, if string "hi" is not given as the first input, it doesn't detect ie if we are giving input in the order "abcd" , "hi" it is not detecting... I am running the code in tclsh using command prompt in windows OS

Comment: @Glenn That didn't work.... I need the code to detect the string "hi", only when it is typed alone ie not for strings "hiabc" or abchidef" or "abchi".... Something like "^hi$" in Tcl

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that can go wrong, but the option most likely is that there's some sort of extra whitespace after the text that you are expecting; Expect sees *all* the characters, not just the printable ones. It could be a space, it could be a newline. If you know what it is, add that into what you are expecting. Otherwise, you need a more complex regular expression:

```
# RE in braces because of the backslash; \s matches *ALL* types of whitespace
expect {^hi\s*$}
send "found it!"
```

Another option is to switch RE matching modes. Expect operates in full-buffer mode by default (it's the only sensible option in the most complex scenarios) but you can put it into line-oriented:

```
# The ‘n’ is mnemonically for Newline-aware
expect {(?n)^hi$}
send "found it!"
```